# how to add custom link on wordpress admin sidebar

Tags: wordpress

How to add custom link on wordpress admin sidebar without using plugins?
For example, i want to add "Google.com" link. How should i do this?

I tried this:
Added next code to admin-bar.php

```
function mycustomlink() {
global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent' => 'new-content',
    'id' => 'mycustomlinkId',
    'title' => __('Custom link'),
    'href' => admin_url( 'google.com'),
    'meta' => false 
));}
```

And added next code to class-wp-admin-bar.php

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'mycustomlink', 900 );
```

but no results.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your theme's function.php

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'linked_url' );
    function linked_url() {
    add_menu_page( 'linked_url', 'External link', 'read', 'my_slug', '', 'dashicons-text', 1 );
    }

    add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
    function linkedurl_function() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[1][2] = "http://www.example.com";
    }
```

Comment: What if you needed a submenu on this with several links? (One that would expand out like the "Pages" or "Posts" menu item.)

Answer (score 10):

For absolute links, just add this hook to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_link');
function add_custom_menu_link()
{
    add_menu_page('my_custom_link_1', 'Google', 'read', 'https://google.com/', '', 'dashicons-text', 1);
}
```

It also works for relative links, but you'll need to replace the initial slash with the HTML entity `&#47;` to prevent WordPress from stripping it out.

So, for example, you would have to use `&#47;books/563` instead of `/books/563`.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_link');
function add_custom_menu_link()
{
    add_menu_page('my_custom_link_1', 'Google', 'read', "&#47;books/563", '', 'dashicons-text', 1);
}
```