# How to add logo image, link to wordpress admin sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I am setting up some custom wordpress admin area. I would like to know how to add logo image to bottom of wordpress admin sidebar. Something like this: [Wordpress sidebar logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjBHk.png). I would also like for image to be a link.

[how to add custom link on wordpress admin sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978561/how-to-add-custom-link-on-wordpress-admin-sidebar)

I tried this solution, but link is not last in sidebar, and I dont know how to add image and class to link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this wordpress plugin. It should help you to setup a logo to your admin sidebar like this: [Example](https://ps.w.org/ag-custom-admin/assets/screenshot-9.png?rev=1784295)

Link to the plugin: [Plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ag-custom-admin/)

Comment: Thank you for solution, but that's not exactly what i nedd. I would like to add logo in php. SOmething like example posed above, in my question.